# Resolving merge conflict on feature branch doesn't work for all master branches

Tags: git, github, merge, git-merge, git-pull

I have three `master` branches

- `master`
- `master-alpha`
- `master-beta`

All of these branches have `100` commits and are `This branch is even with master`.

I have three 'feature' branches.

- `feature-brooklyn` (`master` ... `feature-brooklyn`)
- `feature-staten-island` (`master` ... `feature-brooklyn` ... `feature-staten-island`)
- `feature-manhattan` (`master` ... `feature-manhattan`)

Each are branches off from `master` and `feature-staten-island` makes fundamental changes to `master` so it's been merged with `feature-brooklyn` already.

Here's the setup.

1. I make a PR to add `feature-brooklyn` into `master-beta`. There are no issues.
2. I make a PR to add `feature-staten-island` into `master-beta` there's a merge conflict. So I merge `master-beta` into `feature-staten-island` and then push the update to `feature-staten-island`.

This works and I can merge.

The issue I'm finding is this:

1. I now make a PR to add `feature-brooklyn` into `master-alpha`. Works.
2. I make a PR to add `feature-staten-island` to `master-alpha`, and there's still a merge conflict.

Why when I resolve the merge conflict for the feature branch with another branch and then update the feature branch, does is still have a conflict when I'm merging on another branch with the exact same code?

My goal is to have three clean feature branches that can be easily merged into the three master branches. I'm not understanding why once I fix a merge conflict on for one of the master branches why there's still a conflict when I try and merge it into the other master branch.

Answer (score 1):

When you resolved the conflict between `master-beta` and `feature-staten-island`, you probably chose to keep the code on `feature-staten-island`.

That means `master-beta` and `master-alpha` were no longer identical. You had to resolve the same merge conflict because the conflicting code still existed between `master-alpha` and `feature-staten-island`.

Git will flag a conflict every time there is conflicting code in a merge. You can try using `git merge branch -X ours` to tell Git to prefer the version on your current branch, or `git merge branch -X theirs` to prefer the other branch's version. (I don't think this is the best workflow, but it is possible.)

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because the source line(s) that is(are) causing the conflict with your feature branch is still present **in each of the master branches**.  For example, let's say each master branch has a commit, **past the point at which the feature branches were branched**, which does the following:

```
a = 1;
```

Now, on `feature-staten-island`, there's a commit which does the following, on the same line:

```
a = b + 3;
```

To resolve the conflict, let's say you really wanted this:

```
a = b + 1;
```

Your conflict resolution, then, when merging `master-beta` *into* `feature-staten-island`, would be to have `a = b + 1;` on `feature-staten-island`.  But, since this is still different from the `a = 1;` on `master-beta`, you still have to resolve the conflicting line *on* `master-beta` when you merged `feature-staten-island` back.  Now `master-beta` also has the correct line `a = b + 1;`.

Now, since `master-alpha` and `master` are at the same original commit ref as `master-beta`, they also will still have the conflicting line `a = 1;`, i.e. they will still be *different* than what's on `feature-staten-island`, which has the correct line `a = b + 1;`.  The *manner* in which they are different has changed, since the corrected line on `feature-staten-island` is now `a = b + 1;` instead of the original `a = b + 3;`, but the lines still conflict nonetheless.  Therefore, you'll have to do the same conflict resolution between `feature-staten-island` and each of the remaining `master-XXX` branches.

Make sense?